# jqgrid custom_func not executing with blank field, can't prevent blank record

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using PHPGrid which sits over top of jqgrid. I have a validation function that is supposed to make sure the record's name is unique and that the name is not blank and > 2 characters. The function executes on the inline editing form if someone clicks add and then types something and hits enter. However if they just hit add then enter it doesn't execute and sends the data to save.

```
{
    "name":"school_name",
    "index":"school_name",
    "hidden":false,
    "width":200,
    "edittype":"text",
    "editable":true,
    "editoptions":{"size":"30"},
    "editrules":{"edithidden":false,"required":false,"custom":true,"custom_func":validate_school_name}
},
```

there is the column definition

```
function validate_school_name(val, colname){
    var names = $("[aria-describedby='school_school_name']");

    msg = "";
    alert("Val: "+val);
    if(val =="" || val.length <= 2){
        return [false,"You must enter a school name to continue."]
    }

    for(i=0; i<names.length; i++){
        msg += ""+names[i].innerHTML+" = "+val+"\n" ;
        if(names[i].innerHTML == val){
            return [false," already exists please select a different name"]
        }
    }
    return [true,""];   
}
```

there is the validate function I am running.

Any ideas how to get this to execute on that blank record will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From some basic testing it seems that if required is set to false in editrules, the validation function is not called.  Unfortunetly if you set it to true it checks for an empty value (with a generic message) before the custom validator is called.

however it may still work for you because it will force them to select something in that field and then when they do it will be validated in your custom function

Comment: Gotcha I will try that out and get back to you.